# Select rows from one data.frame that are not present in a second data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, compare, set-difference

I have two data.frames:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])
```

I want to find the rows a1 have that a2 doesn't.

Is there a built in function for this type of operation?

(p.s: I did write a solution for it, I am simply curious if someone already made a more crafted code)

Here is my solution:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])

rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2  <- function(a1,a2)
{
    a1.vec <- apply(a1, 1, paste, collapse = "")
    a2.vec <- apply(a2, 1, paste, collapse = "")
    a1.without.a2.rows <- a1[!a1.vec %in% a2.vec,]
    return(a1.without.a2.rows)
}
rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2(a1,a2)
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it will give you the elements that are in common. This can be done with Paul Murrell's package [`compare`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compare/index.html):

```
library(compare)
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
comparison <- compare(a1,a2,allowAll=TRUE)
comparison$tM
#  a b
#1 1 a
#2 2 b
#3 3 c
```

The function `compare` gives you a lot of flexibility in terms of what kind of comparisons are allowed (e.g. changing order of elements of each vector, changing order and names of variables, shortening variables, changing case of strings). From this, you should be able to figure out what was missing from one or the other. For example (this is not very elegant):

```
difference <-
   data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(a1),function(i)setdiff(a1[,i],comparison$tM[,i])))
colnames(difference) <- colnames(a1)
difference
#  a b
#1 4 d
#2 5 e
```

Comment: I find this function confusing. I thought it would work for me, but it seems to only work as shown above if one set contains identically matching rows of the other set. Consider this case: `a2 <- data.frame(a = c(1:3, 1), b = c(letters[1:3], "c"))`. Leave `a1` the same. Now try the comparison. It's not clear to me even in reading the options what the proper way is to list only common elements.

Answer (score 185):

`sqldf` provides a nice solution

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])

require(sqldf)

a1NotIna2 <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM a1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM a2')
```

And the rows which are in both data frames:

```
a1Ina2 <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM a1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM a2')
```

The new version of `dplyr` has a function, `anti_join`, for exactly these kinds of comparisons

```
require(dplyr) 
anti_join(a1,a2)
```

And `semi_join` to filter rows in `a1` that are also in `a2`

```
semi_join(a1,a2)
```

Comment: is there a reason why anti_join would return a null DF, as would sqldf, but the functions identical(a1,a2) and all.equal() would contradict that?

Comment: Just wanted to add here that anti_join and semi_join would not work in some cases like mine. I was getting "Error: Columns must be 1d atomic vectors or lists" for my data frame. Maybe I could process my data so that these functions work. Sqldf worked right out of the gate!

Comment: @AkshayGaur it should just be a data format or data cleaning problem; sqldf is just sql everything is pre-processed to be like nromal DB such that we could just run sql on the data.

Answer (score 109):

In *dplyr*:

```
setdiff(a1,a2)
```

Basically, `setdiff(bigFrame, smallFrame)` gets you the extra records in the first table.

In the SQLverse this is called a

[image: Left Excluding Join Venn Diagram]

For good descriptions of all join options and set subjects, this is one of the best summaries I've seen put together to date: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/sql-joins

But back to this question - here are the results for the `setdiff()` code when using the OP's data:

```
> a1
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e

> a2
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c

> setdiff(a1,a2)
  a b
1 4 d
2 5 e
```

Or even `anti_join(a1,a2)` will get you the same results.
For more info: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Since the OP asks for items in `a1` that are not in `a2`, don't you want to use something like `semi_join(a1, a2, by = c('a','b'))` ? In the answer by "Rickard", I see that `semi_join` was suggested.

Comment: Sure! Another great choice, too; particularly if you have dataframes with only a join key and differing column names.

Comment: setdiff is from lubridate::setdiff and not from library(dplyr)

Comment: @mtelesha - Hmm, the docs and source code for _dplyr_ show it being there: (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/setops.html ,  https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/sets.). Additionally, when the dplyr library is loaded it even reports masking the base `setdiff()` function that works on two vectors: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html. Maybe you have loaded the _lubridate_ library after _dplyr_ and it is suggesting it as the source in the tabcomplete listing?

Comment: There is a conflict between lubridate and dplyr, see https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/693

Comment: Also consider `dplyr::intersection`

Answer (score 46):

It is certainly not efficient for this particular purpose, but what I often do in these situations is to insert indicator variables in each data.frame and then merge:

```
a1$included_a1 <- TRUE
a2$included_a2 <- TRUE
res <- merge(a1, a2, all=TRUE)
```

missing values in included_a1 will note which rows are missing in a1. similarly for a2.

One problem with your solution is that the column orders must match. Another problem is that it is easy to imagine situations where the rows are coded as the same when in fact are different. The advantage of using merge is that you get for free all error checking that is necessary for a good solution.

Comment: So... in looking for a missing value, you create another missing value... How do you find the missing value(s) in `included_a1`? :-/

Comment: use is.na() and subset, or dplyr::filter

Comment: Thank you for teaching a way without installing a new library!

Answer (score 31):

I wrote a package (https://github.com/alexsanjoseph/compareDF) since I had the same issue.

```
  > df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5], row = 1:5)
  > df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3], row = 1:3)
  > df_compare = compare_df(df1, df2, "row")

  > df_compare$comparison_df
    row chng_type a b
  1   4         + 4 d
  2   5         + 5 e
```

A more complicated example:

```
library(compareDF)
df1 = data.frame(id1 = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710",
                         "Hornet 4 Drive", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D"),
                 id2 = c("Maz", "Maz", "Dat", "Hor", "Dus", "Mer"),
                 hp = c(110, 110, 181, 110, 245, 62),
                 cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 4),
                 qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 33.00, 19.44, 15.84, 20.00))

df2 = data.frame(id1 = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710",
                         "Hornet 4 Drive", " Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant"),
                 id2 = c("Maz", "Maz", "Dat", "Hor", "Dus", "Val"),
                 hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105),
                 cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6),
                 qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22))

> df_compare$comparison_df
    grp chng_type                id1 id2  hp cyl  qsec
  1   1         -  Hornet Sportabout Dus 175   8 17.02
  2   2         +         Datsun 710 Dat 181   4 33.00
  3   2         -         Datsun 710 Dat  93   4 18.61
  4   3         +         Duster 360 Dus 245   8 15.84
  5   7         +          Merc 240D Mer  62   4 20.00
  6   8         -            Valiant Val 105   6 20.22
```

The package also has an html_output command for quick checking

> df_compare$html_output
>   [image]

Comment: your compareDF is exactly what I need , and have done  a good job with small sets.However:1)  Not working with a set 50Million rows with 3 column (say) it says out of memory with 32 GB RAM. 2) I also see HTML takes some time to write, can the same output be sent to TEXT file?

Comment: 1) Yeah 50 million rows is A LOT OF data, just to hold in memory ;). I'm aware that it is not great with large datasets, so you might have to do some sort of chunking.
2) you can give the argument - limit_html = 0, to avoid it printing to a HTML. The same output is in compare_output$comparison_df which you can write to a CSV/TEXT fule using native R functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alex Joseph , I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Alex Joseph, thanks for the input the text format did work but found an issue , raised it under: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880218/compare-df-in-r-truncating-trailing-zero

Comment: It can't handle different numbers of columns. I got an error `The two data frames have different columns!`

Comment: @PeyM87 - If the columns are different it's very easily visible from the names(df) right? What is the behaviour you're expecting? If you can create a in issue reprex on the github, I can take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexJoseph: I have dataframe1 with X number of columns. After some time, new data comes in and I have dataframe2 with Y number of colums, in which some columns are always common. I thought this compare would for instance SUM the common columns and Add columns if there are any new.

Comment: If you have columns changing, doing a setdiff(names(df1), names(df2)) is probably the best approach

Comment: Works great, thanks so much, any easy method of identifying which dataset the change is in? For instance, the + is from df2 in the second row above.

Comment: @Lowpar - You can try the change_markers, option for this

Comment: Thanks @AlexJoseph, I might be missing something, but I like the markers, my challenge is, if I find a difference, then how do I know which dataset it came from? So if I have dataset a and dataset b, and I see there is a +, any way of knowing automatically is the + in dataset a or dataset b? Super thankful for your amazing package! You are a boss!!

Comment: No worries @Lowpar - The parameters for the function are `df_new` and `df_old`. If there is a `+` marker, it means that the `df_new` data.frame has it and `-` marker means that `df_old` data.frame has it changed. In the above example, Datsun 710, has a value of 181 HP in the new data frame and 93 HP in the old data.frame

Comment: Makes complete sense now. I was thinking + meant that a value was included, while - meant a value was missing. But seems very intuitive now.

Answer (score 22):

You could use the [`daff` package](https://github.com/edwindj/daff) (which wraps the [`daff.js` library](https://paulfitz.github.io/daff/) using the [`V8` package](https://github.com/jeroenooms/v8)):

```r
library(daff)

diff_data(data_ref = a2,
          data = a1)
```

produces the following difference object:

```r
Daff Comparison: ‘a2’ vs. ‘a1’ 
  First 6 and last 6 patch lines:
   @@   a   b
1 ... ... ...
2       3   c
3 +++   4   d
4 +++   5   e
5 ... ... ...
6 ... ... ...
7       3   c
8 +++   4   d
9 +++   5   e
```

The tabular diff format is described [here](https://paulfitz.github.io/daff-doc/spec.html) and should be pretty self-explanatory. The lines with `+++` in the first column `@@` are the ones which are new in `a1` and not present in `a2`.

The difference object can be used to `patch_data()`, to store the difference for documentation purposes using `write_diff()` or to **visualize the difference using `render_diff()`**:

```r
render_diff(
    diff_data(data_ref = a2,
              data = a1)
)
```

generates a neat HTML output:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Using `diffobj` package:

```
library(diffobj)

diffPrint(a1, a2)
diffObj(a1, a2)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I adapted the `merge` function to get this functionality. On larger dataframes it uses less memory than the full merge solution. And I can play with the names of the key columns.

Another solution is to use the library `prob`.

```
#  Derived from src/library/base/R/merge.R
#  Part of the R package, http://www.R-project.org
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  A copy of the GNU General Public License is available at
#  http://www.r-project.org/Licenses/

XinY <-
    function(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)), by.x = by, by.y = by,
             notin = FALSE, incomparables = NULL,
             ...)
{
    fix.by <- function(by, df)
    {
        ## fix up 'by' to be a valid set of cols by number: 0 is row.names
        if(is.null(by)) by <- numeric(0L)
        by <- as.vector(by)
        nc <- ncol(df)
        if(is.character(by))
            by <- match(by, c("row.names", names(df))) - 1L
        else if(is.numeric(by)) {
            if(any(by < 0L) || any(by > nc))
                stop("'by' must match numbers of columns")
        } else if(is.logical(by)) {
            if(length(by) != nc) stop("'by' must match number of columns")
            by <- seq_along(by)[by]
        } else stop("'by' must specify column(s) as numbers, names or logical")
        if(any(is.na(by))) stop("'by' must specify valid column(s)")
        unique(by)
    }

    nx <- nrow(x <- as.data.frame(x)); ny <- nrow(y <- as.data.frame(y))
    by.x <- fix.by(by.x, x)
    by.y <- fix.by(by.y, y)
    if((l.b <- length(by.x)) != length(by.y))
        stop("'by.x' and 'by.y' specify different numbers of columns")
    if(l.b == 0L) {
        ## was: stop("no columns to match on")
        ## returns x
        x
    }
    else {
        if(any(by.x == 0L)) {
            x <- cbind(Row.names = I(row.names(x)), x)
            by.x <- by.x + 1L
        }
        if(any(by.y == 0L)) {
            y <- cbind(Row.names = I(row.names(y)), y)
            by.y <- by.y + 1L
        }
        ## create keys from 'by' columns:
        if(l.b == 1L) {                  # (be faster)
            bx <- x[, by.x]; if(is.factor(bx)) bx <- as.character(bx)
            by <- y[, by.y]; if(is.factor(by)) by <- as.character(by)
        } else {
            ## Do these together for consistency in as.character.
            ## Use same set of names.
            bx <- x[, by.x, drop=FALSE]; by <- y[, by.y, drop=FALSE]
            names(bx) <- names(by) <- paste("V", seq_len(ncol(bx)), sep="")
            bz <- do.call("paste", c(rbind(bx, by), sep = "\r"))
            bx <- bz[seq_len(nx)]
            by <- bz[nx + seq_len(ny)]
        }
        comm <- match(bx, by, 0L)
        if (notin) {
            res <- x[comm == 0,]
        } else {
            res <- x[comm > 0,]
        }
    }
    ## avoid a copy
    ## row.names(res) <- NULL
    attr(res, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(nrow(res))
    res
}


XnotinY <-
    function(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)), by.x = by, by.y = by,
             notin = TRUE, incomparables = NULL,
             ...)
{
    XinY(x,y,by,by.x,by.y,notin,incomparables)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your example data does not have any duplicates, but your solution handle them automatically. This means that potentially some of the answers won't match to results of your function in case of duplicates.
Here is my solution which address duplicates the same way as yours. It also scales great!

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])
rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2  <- function(a1,a2)
{
    a1.vec <- apply(a1, 1, paste, collapse = "")
    a2.vec <- apply(a2, 1, paste, collapse = "")
    a1.without.a2.rows <- a1[!a1.vec %in% a2.vec,]
    return(a1.without.a2.rows)
}

library(data.table)
setDT(a1)
setDT(a2)

# no duplicates - as in example code
r <- fsetdiff(a1, a2)
all.equal(r, rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2(a1,a2))
#[1] TRUE

# handling duplicates - make some duplicates
a1 <- rbind(a1, a1, a1)
a2 <- rbind(a2, a2, a2)
r <- fsetdiff(a1, a2, all = TRUE)
all.equal(r, rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2(a1,a2))
#[1] TRUE
```

It needs data.table 1.9.8+

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is too simplistic, but I used this solution and I find it very useful when I have a primary key that I can use to compare data sets. Hope it can help.

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
different.names <- (!a1$a %in% a2$a)
not.in.a2 <- a1[different.names,]
```

Comment: How is this different from what OP already tried? You've used the exact same code like Tal to compare a single column instead of the whole row (which was the requirement)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution based on match_df in plyr.
Here's plyr's match_df:

```
match_df <- function (x, y, on = NULL) 
{
    if (is.null(on)) {
        on <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
        message("Matching on: ", paste(on, collapse = ", "))
    }
    keys <- join.keys(x, y, on)
    x[keys$x %in% keys$y, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

We can modify it to negate:

```
library(plyr)
negate_match_df <- function (x, y, on = NULL) 
{
    if (is.null(on)) {
        on <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
        message("Matching on: ", paste(on, collapse = ", "))
    }
    keys <- join.keys(x, y, on)
    x[!(keys$x %in% keys$y), , drop = FALSE]
}
```

Then:

```
diff <- negate_match_df(a1,a2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `subset`:

```
missing<-subset(a1, !(a %in% a2$a))
```

Comment: This answer works for the OP's scenario. What about the more general case when the variable "a" does match between the two data.frames("a1" and "a2"), but the variable "b" does not?

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses both `data.table` and `fastmatch` for increased speed.

```
library("data.table")
library("fastmatch")

a1 <- setDT(data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5]))
a2 <- setDT(data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3]))

compare_rows <- a1$a %fin% a2$a
# the %fin% function comes from the `fastmatch` package

added_rows <- a1[which(compare_rows == FALSE)]

added_rows

#    a b
# 1: 4 d
# 2: 5 e
```

Answer (score 0):

Really fast comparison, to get count of differences.
Using specific column name.

```
colname = "CreatedDate" # specify column name
index <- match(colname, names(source_df)) # get index name for column name
sel <- source_df[, index] == target_df[, index] # get differences, gives you dataframe with TRUE and FALSE values
table(sel)["FALSE"] # count of differences
table(sel)["TRUE"] # count of matches
```

For complete dataframe, do not provide column or index name

```
sel <- source_df[, ] == target_df[, ] # gives you dataframe with TRUE and FALSE values
table(sel)["FALSE"] # count of differences
table(sel)["TRUE"] # count of matches
```