# R: remove rows from one data frame that are in another

Tags: r

I have two data frames df1 and df2. They have the same (two) columns. I want to remove the rows from df1 that are in df2.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with several packages. But here's how to do it with base R.

```
df1 <-matrix(1:6,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
df2 <-matrix(1:10,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
all <-rbind(df1,df2) #rbind the columns
#use !duplicated fromLast = FALSE and fromLast = TRUE to get unique rows.
all[!duplicated(all,fromLast = FALSE)&!duplicated(all,fromLast = TRUE),] 

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    8
[2,]    9   10
```

Comment: I like this, but I don't understand it. I like it because (unlike the other answer) it leaves all three variables in my dataframes intact (the other answer deletes those and adds a new "v1" that seem to be the row.names from one of the original DFs). I don't understand it as this is the first time I have seen "!duplicated" used - plus (or "and"?) I don't understand how the "fromLast" "FALSE" and "TRUE" parts work. Something else to study. But it is an elegant solution.

Comment: Hi, Does the solution also work for more than 2 times duplicated rows?

Comment: @eclairs If I understand your question correctly, yes this solution will exclude multiple duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df2 <-matrix(1:6,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
df1 <-matrix(1:10,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

data.frame(v1=setdiff(df1[,1], df2[,1]), v2=setdiff(df1[,2], df2[,2]))
  v1 v2
1  7  8
2  9 10
```

Note that `df1` and `df2` are the same as Lapointe's but in the other way around, because you want to remove the rows from df1 that are in df2, so setdiff removes elements from `x` that are contained in `y`. See `?setdiff`

you'll get the same result as Lapointe's

Answer (score 2):

I got an easy one considering you have a variable (var_match) that matches between the two dataframes:

```
df_1_minus_2 <- df_1[which(!df_1$var_match %in% df_2$var_match),]
```