# Remove the rows in matrix A, which appear in the matrix B(B is a subset of A)

Tags: r

I have a matrix A:

```
> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]    1    2    3
[5,]    4    5    6
[6,]    7    8    9
```

and a matrix B:

```
> B
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

I want to delete the rows in matrix A, which appear in B.
And the result should be:

```
> C
      [,1] [,2] [,3]    
[1,]    7    8    9
[2,]    7    8    9
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907359/r-remove-rows-from-one-data-frame-that-are-in-another

Comment: You could do sometype of an anti-join- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join). Using `data.table`, this could be `library(data.table);DTA <- data.table(A);DTB <- data.table(B);DTA[!DTB, on = names(DTA)]`

Comment: @GauravTaneja it works and it's a little tricky, thanks a lot

Comment: @HuaYoung it actually doesn't work for your example. Simply because you have two duplicated rows in your first matrix which doesn't appear in your second matrix and hence also got removed.

Comment: @DavidArenburg you are right, I think I should update my problem. Actually I don't care the duplicated rows. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am sorry that I cannot update the example, because some people have answered me. The rows of the real data that I am using are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
as.matrix(anti_join(as.data.frame(A), as.data.frame(B)))
#     V1 V2 V3
#[1,]  7  8  9
#[2,]  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

First create the above two matricies

```
A <- matrix(rep(c(1:9),2),ncol=3,byrow = T)
B <- matrix(1:6,ncol=3,byrow = T)
```

Get the index of rows to be removed

```
Indx <- apply(B,1,function(x) apply(A,1,function(y) all.equal(x,y)))
Indx <- apply(Indx,1,any)
```

Remove the rows from first matrix

```
A[-which(Indx),]
```

Comment: It works for me. Although there are some warning messages, it doesn't matter.

Comment: See @akrun answer. Its perfect. You can also explore other join operations in dplyr package.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `match_df` function inside `plyr` package.

```
    library(plyr)
    A = matrix(rep(1:9,2),nrow=6,byrow=T)
    B = matrix(1:6,nrow=2,byrow=T)

    M_ROWS = as.numeric(rownames(match_df(data.frame(A),data.frame(B))))
    # Matching on: X1, X2, X3

    Result <- A[-M_ROWS,]
    Result
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
    # [1,]    7    8    9
    # [2,]    7    8    9
```