# Extract rows in first data.frame for which certain values are not found in second data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to eliminate from a first dataframe all of the rows for which a certain value is in a second dataframe.

Using the R programming language for statistical data analysis.

This is the first question I post here, so bear with me if you please ;)

I work with confidential data, so I recreated the problem with an example.

```
Name=c("Bussieres", "Nelson")
Fname=c("Paul", "Robert")
Tel=c(123,234)
comp1=data.frame(Name, Fname, Tel)

Name=c("Bussieres","Bussieres","Nelson","Nelson")
Fname=c("Robert","Paul","Paul","Paula")
Tel=c(123,234,345,456)
comp2=data.frame(Name, Fname, Tel)
```

comp1 returns:

```
   Name Fname Tel
1 Bussieres   Paul 123
2    Nelson Robert 234
```

comp2 returns:

```
   Name Fname Tel
1 Bussieres Robert 123
2 Bussieres   Paul 234
3    Nelson   Paul 345
4    Nelson  Paula 456
```

Now, what I want is to return the rows of comp1 for which "Name" and "Fname" are not identical in comp2.

The expected return, to be stored in a new dataframe comp3, would be (**slight edit done here, posted erronous expected results**):

```
   Name Fname Tel
1    Nelson Robert 234
```

My first attempts were with using the match function, but that didn't quite work.

The following attempt at a for loop also didn't work.

```
for (i in comp1[,"Name"]){for (j in comp3[,"Name"]){if i!=j return comp3=x1["Name"==i,]}}
```

I'm surprised that I can't find basic (primitive) functions in R to do this, as excluding certain observations from a data set would be a very routine procedure.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_data_frames/ and this is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(comp1, key=c("Name", "Fname"))
dt2 <- data.table(comp2, key=c("Name", "Fname"))
dt1[!dt2]

#      Name  Fname Tel
# 1: Nelson Robert 234
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant different, so I'll correct the output in the question.

Comment: The answer proposed by Arun worked. Thanks!
I installed the data.table package, and run the above script.
To eliminate all errors from data collection, I also capitalised the Name and Fname values.
I did this via Excel however, so I'll be looking for a solution in R to this issue at another time ;)