# Comparing two dataframes and outputting unique values

Tags: r

I have two dataframes,

```
A(514 rows)

1 2
2 3      
4 5
1 3
5 6
...

B(696 rows)

1 2
3 4
4 5
1 3
5 7
5 6
.....
```

I want to get those rows and their corresponding columns which are present in B but not in A.
For example, the result will be,

```
3 4
5 7
```

How can I do it in R?

I tried using this post answers: [Compare two data.frames to find the rows in data.frame 1 that are not present in data.frame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in)

But here, the first answer difference doesnt give the correct output.

Comment: It is a little unclear.  Do you want the matching columns in B, but not the rows present in A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
colIndx <- colnames(B)[colnames(B) %in% colnames(A)]
rowIndx <- !as.character(interaction(B)) %in%  as.character(interaction(A[colIndx]))
 B[rowIndx,]
#   V1 V2
#2  3  4
#5  5  7
```

#### data

```
 A <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L), V2 = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 
 3L, 6L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

 B <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 
 5L, 3L, 7L, 6L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```