# Comparing two dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to compare two dataframes that explain the same things, but they came from different ways to obtain them.

So I need to obtain a df where every single value is compared to the respective on the other df, and give to me TRUE if values are identical, FALSE if they aren't.

I write an example just for better explain:

df1

```
>    1  2  3  
> 1 AT GC CC 
> 2 AG GC CT 
> 3 GG TT <NA>
```

df2

```
>    1  2   3  
> 1 AT <NA> GG 
> 2 AG  GC  CG 
> 3 GG  TT  AA
```

result

```
>      1     2     3  
> 1 TRUE <NA>  FALSE 
> 2 TRUE TRUE  FALSE 
> 3 TRUE TRUE  <NA>
```

I've seen here a result

[Comparing two similar dataframes and finding different values between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728123/comparing-two-similar-dataframes-and-finding-different-values-between-them?rq=1)

but in my df doesn't work if one of the df has an NA (R gave me TRUE).

Also, I aspected that if I change the order of the df in `mapply()`, I will obtain the same result, but it's not true in my case. The dataframes also have different levels, so `df1==df2` doesn't work.

I also will ask to you how I will count the FALSE in the result. Is there something like `is.na()`?

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `==` to get a logical matrix

```
(df1 == df2) & !is.na(df1) & !is.na(df2)
#    1     2     3
#1 TRUE FALSE FALSE
#2 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#3 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

If the columns are `factor` class, then we can compare colwise with `mapply/Map`

```
mapply(function(x, y) {i1 <- as.character(x)==as.character(y)
         replace(i1, is.na(i1), FALSE)}, df1, df2)
```

Or compare as `matrix` and then convert the NA to `FALSE`

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df1) == as.matrix(df2)
m1[is.na(m1)] <- FALSE
```

Comment: I've got this error: `Error in Ops.factor(left, right) : level sets of factors are different`

Comment: @mppd It is better to compare `character` class columns, `i.e. `df1[] <-lapply(df1, as.character); df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)` and then do the comparison

Comment: I've seen that if in one of the df I've NA, in the end I've NA, but also if it's a false statement. How can I maintain a NA if in df1 is NA and in df2 not and vice-versa, and also obtain a FALSE statement if AT in df 1 is different then AA in df2, for example?

Comment: @mppd In that case, you just remove one of the `is.na` i.e. `(df1 == df2) & !is.na(df2)`

Comment: Last question and I'm done! (: what if there's `<NA>` in df1 and `<NA>` in df2 and I want to see `<NA>` too at the end?

Comment: @mppd In that case, just do `(df1 == df2)`

Comment: Very very very helpful! You made my day (and my job). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option,

```
df1 == replace(df2, is.na(df2), 'NA')
```

or If both data frames contain NAs,

```
replace(df1, is.na(df1), 'NA') == replace(df2, is.na(df2), 'NA')
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It corrects the mistakes with na, but gives a TRUE value when it doesn't is.

Comment: I don't get it. So if you have two values 'NA' and 'NA', you want it to display FALSE?

Comment: no, if in df1 there's AG and in df2 there's NA, I see FALSE and it's good, but with your code, if I have in df1 AG and in df2 TT, I will see TRUE  and it's not what I need. I hope it's better explained now

Comment: @mppd I get FALSE for that. I get the same result you are after

Comment: I've setting before `df1[] <-lapply(df1, as.character); df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)` because levels are differents. But at the end I obtain a table that's all FALSE.

Comment: At the end I've done this:
`x <- df1 == replace(df2, is.na(df2), 'NA')
y <- df2 == replace(df1, is.na(df1), 'NA')`
z <- x == y