# Difference between the data in Table A and Table B

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Let us assume we are using Oracle Database:

Table A  has columns: price, pricelist, currency. 
Table B has columns:  price, pricelist, currency, status.

sample Data :

```
Table A 

price, pricelist, currency
123 , PL_10122016, EUR
111 , PL_10122016, GBP
141 , PL_10122016, USD

Table B 

price, pricelist, currency,status
123 , PL_10122016, EUR,0
111 , PL_10122016, GBP,0
143 , PL_10122016, USD,0
```

I would like to find the rows in Table A that are not present in Table B.

```
Expected Output : 
141 , PL_10122016, USD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using Minus**

```
WITH tablea  (price, pricelist, currency) AS
(SELECT 123 , 'pl_10122016', 'eur' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 111 , 'pl_10122016', 'gbp' FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT 141 , 'pl_10122016', 'usd' FROM dual )
,tableb (price, pricelist, currency,status) AS 
(SELECT 123 , 'pl_10122016', 'eur',0 FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT 111 , 'pl_10122016', 'gbp',0  FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 143 , 'pl_10122016', 'usd',0 FROM dual )
SELECT price , pricelist , currency  FROM tablea
MINUS
SELECT price , pricelist , currency  FROM tableb;

Result:
PRICE   PRICELIST   CURRENCY
141 pl_10122016 usd
```

**using Left join**

```
WITH tablea  (price, pricelist, currency) AS
(SELECT 123 , 'pl_10122016', 'eur' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 111 , 'pl_10122016', 'gbp' FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT 141 , 'pl_10122016', 'usd' FROM dual )
,tableb (price, pricelist, currency,status) AS 
(SELECT 123 , 'pl_10122016', 'eur',0 FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT 111 , 'pl_10122016', 'gbp',0  FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 143 , 'pl_10122016', 'usd',0 FROM dual )
SELECT a.*
FROM tablea a 
LEFT JOIN tableb b
  ON  a.price = b.price AND a.pricelist = b.pricelist AND a.currency = b.currency
  WHERE b.price IS NULL AND b.pricelist IS NULL AND b.currency IS NULL;

Result:
PRICE   PRICELIST   CURRENCY
141 pl_10122016 usd
```

You can do the same with RIGHT JOIN as well as FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: The Minus somehow does not do the Job. :-(

Comment: I have added some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched stackoverflow before asking? There are already answers to similar questions. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in).

His solution:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])

rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2  <- function(a1,a2)
{
    a1.vec <- apply(a1, 1, paste, collapse = "")
    a2.vec <- apply(a2, 1, paste, collapse = "")
    a1.without.a2.rows <- a1[!a1.vec %in% a2.vec,]
    return(a1.without.a2.rows)
}
rows.in.a1.that.are.not.in.a2(a1,a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.price, A.pricelist, A.currency
    FROM TableA A 
    LEFT JOIN TableB B
      ON  A.price = B.price  
      AND A.pricelist = B.pricelist
      AND A.currency = B.currency
```

Until here you have matching rows from TableB and all rows from TableA (matching and non-matching) . The followig condition will reduce the results to only non-matching rows:

```
      WHERE B.price is NULL
      AND B.pricelist is NULL
      AND B.currency is NULL
```