# Match multiple columns in two data frames and print unequal

Tags: r

So I have two large (in some part different) data frames, first is named **sifrant** and consist of:

```
   IDP   PREDMET   ID    NAME
1 120_1  ustanove  _18 Barbara
2 120_1  ustanove _301  Mojca 
3 200_1  zakonod  _954  Klara
```

And other data frame is dalled **baza**

```
predmet sifpredm izvajalec1 sifizv1 izvajalec2 sifizv2 izvajalec3 sifizv3 izvajalec4 sifizv4 izvajalec5 sifizv5
ustanove    120_1   Barbara      _18     Mojca     _301     Klara     _954         -2      -2         -2      -2
ustanove    120_1   Barbara      _18     Mojca     _301         -2      -2         -2      -2         -2      -2
```

Boath data frames should have equal values in next colums: `IDP==sifpredm` and `ID==sifizv1, siizv2, sifizv3, and so on`.

Now I would like to match this columns
 `IDP with sifpredm` and
 `ID with sifizv1 and sifizv2 and sifizv3` and so on.

Based on match, I would like to print `IDP, ID and NAME` that do not have match in **sifrant** **(i.e., is missing in sifrant and is present in baza)**

Comparing two data frames I can see that in data frame `sifrant` lecturer  Klara is missing IDP 120_1. So my output should print which sifpredm, sifizv and izvajalec are in `baza` but not in `sifrant`. In my case **sifrant** is missing class with ID number 120_1, lecturer ID number _954, lecturer name Klara

So far I have tried

```
    merge(sifrant, baza, by.x = "IDP",by.y="sifpredm" , all = T)
```

and

```
 require(sqldf)
    sifrantNotInbaza <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM baza EXCEPT SELECT * FROM sifrant')
```

and

```
library(diffobj)
install.packages("diffobj")
diffPrint(sifrant, baza)
diffObj(sifrant, baza)
```

I've also looked here

[Compare two data.frames to find the rows in data.frame 1 that are not present in data.frame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in)

Here is also dput of both data frames:

```
structure(list(IDP = c("120_1", "120_1"), PREDMET = c("ustanove", 
" ustanove"), ID = c("_18", "_301"), NAME = c("Barbara", "Mojca "
)), .Names = c("IDP", "PREDMET", "ID", "NAME"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))


structure(list(predmet = c("ustanove", "ustanove"), sifpredm = c("120_1", 
"120_1"), izvajalec1 = c("Barbara ", "Barbara "), sifizv1 = c("_18", 
"_18"), izvajalec2 = c("Mojca ", "Mojca "), sifizv2 = c("_301", 
"_301"), izvajalec3 = c("Klara ", "-2"), sifizv3 = c("_954", 
"-2"), izvajalec4 = c(-2L, -2L), sifizv4 = c(-2L, -2L), izvajalec5 = c(-2L, 
-2L), sifizv5 = c(-2L, -2L)), .Names = c("predmet", "sifpredm", 
"izvajalec1", "sifizv1", "izvajalec2", "sifizv2", "izvajalec3", 
"sifizv3", "izvajalec4", "sifizv4", "izvajalec5", "sifizv5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to correct your dput for sifrant. I copied in the table you've got in your description instead. 
Then I would do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
baza2 <- baza %>% 
           gather(contains("sifizv"), 
                key = "sifizv", 
                value = "ID"
                ) %>% 
           select(1:2,ID) %>% 
           unique()
output <- anti_join(baza2, sifrant, by = c("sifpredm" = "IDP", "ID"))
```

This tells you the ID of the missing person. You can then look up their name by using `match` or:

```
left_join(output, sifrant) %>% select(sifpredm, predmet, ID, NAME)
```

Comment: Yes I've missed one row in dput. thx. But your output gives `IDP PREDMET   ID  NAME
1 200_1      zakonod  _954 Klara` but my outpus should be ID of class that is not in sifrant so it should be IDP PREDMET   ID  NAME
1 120_1      ustanove  _954 Klara`

Comment: No, the result is the same, I stil get `200_1` .... So in my example Klara with IDP  120_1 is in `baza` but not in `sifrant`, so my output should look like this:`120_1  ustanove _954  Klara` because this lecture is not in `sifrat` but is in `baza`.

Comment: Edited again. Hopefully it should reflect what you need now.

Comment: Malenkost stari! lp

Comment: Haha :). Legenda :).