# check if a string contains one element of a list with R

Tags: r, regex, loops

I would like to check if at least one element of my data_frame_1 is in data_frame_2 and add it like a new column

my code:

```
library(data.table)

object_to_check <- data.table(c('aaax', 'bbbx', 'cccy', 'dddk', 'mmmt'))
colnames(object_to_check) <- 'x'
list_of_element <- data.table(c('ax', 'kh', 'dk'))
colnames(list_of_element) <- 'y'

Fun2 <- function(element_to_find, string_to_check) {
   element_to_find <- '0'
      if (element_to_find == '0') {
         for (i in 1:length(list_of_element)) {
            m <- lista[i]
            element_to_find <- ifelse(grepl(m, string_to_check, ignore.case = T) == T,string_to_check,'')
         }
      }
   }

object_to_check <- object_to_check[, check := Fun2(check, x)]
```

my code give me this error:

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(object_to_check, , `:=`(check, Fun2(check, x))) :
Adding new column 'check' then assigning NULL (deleting it).
```

I'm stuck on this error and i can't find a solution on my problem. Can sameone help me?

Desired output:

```
x check
aaax ax  
bbbx NA
cccx NA 
dddk dk  
mmmt NA
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in

Comment: Please show your expected output based on the example

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
> df1 <- data.frame(row.names=1:4, var1=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), var2=c(1,2,3,4))
> df2 <- data.frame(row.names=5:7, var1=c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), var2=c(5,2,3))
> df1
   var1 var2
1  TRUE    1
2  TRUE    2
3 FALSE    3
4 FALSE    4
> df2
   var1 var2
5 FALSE    5
6  TRUE    2
7 FALSE    3
```

There are also some other easiest ways are also available. you can use `all.equal(target, current, ...)` function. It does not sort the dataframes. 
Another way is to use `identical()` funtion

Comment: Thanks but i have to check if a string in df2 is contained in a larger string of df1. Identical can't solve my problem i have to use a regular expression to check if string_df2 is in string_df1