# Matching rows to subset by marching ID

Tags: r, matching

I have two data frames

```
df1 = data.frame( Id=c(1, 2, 3), address = c(3130, 5234, 1400))    
df2 = data.frame(Id=c(1,1,2, 3, 3), address = c(5300, 3130, 5430, 5500, 2410))
```

I'm trying to match each address in `df1` against every address in `df2` that  has a matching `Id`, and return a `True` if it matched and a `False` if it didn't.

So the result would be `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two data.frames to find the rows in data.frame 1 that are not present in data.frame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in)

Comment: 3130 is not in `df2$address`

Comment: Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

For both data.frame, combine the `Id` and `address` in each row together using `paste` and then check if the combinations from `df1` are also present in the combinations from `df2` using `%in%`

```
do.call(paste, df1[c("Id", "address")]) %in% do.call(paste, df2[c("Id", "address")])
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

OR

```
df1$Id %in% merge(df1, df2, by = c("Id", "address"))$Id
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) df1[i, 2] %in% df2[df2[,1] == df1[i, 1], 2])
```

Although this returns F, F, F correctly. I think you have mistook 3120 and 3130 as a match.

Comment: They only want to match when the id is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `purrr`:

```
  library(purrr)
  map2_df(df1, df2, ~ .x %in% .y) %>%
    reduce(~ .x == .y)
  #[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**How it works**:

The first function call, `map2_df(df1, df2, ~ .x %in% .y)`, creates a dataframe that shares the same shape as `df1` but is populated with booleans indicating shared membership between `df1` and `df2`:

```
  # A tibble: 4 x 2
    Id    address
    <lgl> <lgl>  
  1 TRUE  TRUE   
  2 TRUE  FALSE  
  3 TRUE  FALSE
```

The second function call, `reduce(~ .x == .y)`, collapses each row by equivalence and yields our final answer:

```
  #[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

By performing a row-wise equivalence, we ensure that only values with a matching `Id` value may return `TRUE`.